# Getting values to childComponents from Parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I need get the calculate values in childComponent for count this values and show in the page.
ChildComponent calculate 2 values (import and ADR) ​​using the parameters that are sent and the input value "contPorcent".

Parent component

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.familys}" var="item" indexVar="index">
<c:TCK_Opp_Contingencia_Rows family="{!item}" ContingMax="{!v.ContingMax}" rowIndex="{!index}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Child component

```
<aura:attribute name="family" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="rowIndex" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="import" type="Decimal"/>
<aura:attribute name="contPorcent" type="Decimal"/>
<aura:attribute name="ADR" type="Decimal"/>
<aura:attribute name="ContingMax" type="Decimal"/>

<aura:registerEvent name="ChangeContingRowEvt" type="c:TCK_ChangeContingRowEvt"/> 

<tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
    <td>
        <ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!v.family}" disabled="true"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ui:inputCurrency class="slds-input" value="{!v.import}" disabled="true"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!v.contPorcent}" change="{!c.changeValue}" format="##%"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ui:inputCurrency class="slds-input" value="{!v.ADR}" disabled="true"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need show in parentComponent the sum of import and ADR.
How can access to this calculate values??

Thanks

Comment: The attributes from the "parent" don't match the "children." Can you please include all the relevant code?

Comment: You can use [Component Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component.htm) to pass values from child to parent.

Comment: I edited the code. All code of parent and js are very long. I use component event for save and return datas, but here, I need get all calculate values, and recalculate if this values are changed (if user input a new values)